# How can I prevent some code duplication for a feed handler

Tags: scala, oop

I have a feed handler and I would like to prevent the data handle again if the value updated is same as previous value, so I have code like this

```
map.get(statisticsOpenAcronym).map { x =>
  var open = x.asInstanceOf[Number].doubleValue();
  if (statistics.open != open) {
    statistics.open = open;
    statistics.changed = true;
  }
}
map.get(statisticsCloseAcronym).map { x =>
  var close = x.asInstanceOf[Number].doubleValue();
  if (statistics.close != close) {
    statistics.close = close;
    statistics.changed = true;
  }
}
```

But then I need to have the [if xxx is difference, the update xxx and set change flag ] replicate again and again.

Just wonder, how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You can compose functions (I had to change some things because I'm not sure of your types):

```
case class Statistic() {
  var open = true
  var close = !open
  var changed = false
}

var statistics = Statistic()


def f(map: Map[String, String], statisticsOpenAcronym: String, statistic: Statistic, condition: Statistic => Boolean, exec: (Statistic, Boolean) => ()) = {
  map.get(statisticsOpenAcronym).map { x =>
    val close = x.asInstanceOf[Boolean]
    if (condition(statistic)) {
      exec(statistic, close)
    }
  }
}


def closeCondition(): Statistic => Boolean = { statistics: Statistic =>
  statistics.close
}

def closeStatistic(): (Statistic, Boolean) => Unit = { (statistics: Statistic, close: Boolean) =>
  statistics.close = close
  statistics.changed = true;
}


f(Map.empty, "acronym", statistics, closeCondition(), closeStatistic())
```

Better yet you could make `closeStatistics` return a new statistic with the parameters you want instead of `Unit`.

The open case is analogue.